# What is the integer value of AF_UNIX?

Tags: java, c, linux, sockets, unix

So, I'm trying to write some JNA code to work with Unix sockets, and I'm trying to reference AF_UNIX for sockets. I looked through some of the gcc included files, but I couldn't find anything.

Comment: Like chrylis said, it may be platform dependant but you can find out what it is on a specific platform by getting the compiler to output it for you [here](http://ideone.com/VhJD0x)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

On my Ubuntu-machine it is defined in `/usr/include/x86_64-linux-gnu/bits/socket.h` as `1`. I haven't checked around in other Unix source trees, but I have a feeling that it is probably defined as `1` in most other Unix dialects.

Comment: "*I have a feeling ...*" hmhm, not so nice for an answer.

Comment: I found it there as well, thanks. It's one for me aswell. Do you know where I could find `SOCK_STREAM` ? I looked in that file and the other ones, no luck.

Comment: I found it in sock_stream.h or something similar! Thanks!

Comment: @alk: Don't be so picky. I already answered the question. I just added a guess about how likely it was that the value would be different on other Unix dialects. Since the poster doesn't have the option of using the system header file, this is relevant information.

Comment: You are right @JesperE. I didn't "looked" at your answer like this, that "*the feeling*" could be seen as an explicit hint to not generalise the answer's 1st sentence.

Comment: The primary purpose (IMHO) of symbolic constants is to make the code *readable*. Changing the numeric value may be useful in circumstances, but in many cases the numeric value is just as permanent as the symbolic one. `AF_UNIX` will never change its value on a given platform, or all existing socket code would break.

Answer (score 3):

It may be platform-dependent, which is why you should use the define. It should be in `sys/socket.h`.

Comment: Question explicitly mentions JNA and Java, which means that including the header file is not an option.

Comment: @JesperE If you're already calling native code, it's really easy.  For example, in C, `int get_AF_UNIX_value(){ return AF_UNIX;}` and call that from Java:  `public static final int AF_UNIX = get_AF_UNIX_value();`, minus any JNI/JNA name mangling.

Comment: Well, yes, but JNA is often used to call native code directly where you don't have the source code and/or do not want to rebuild/modify it.

Comment: If you want a more general solution to this problem, then Jnaerator might be of interest: https://code.google.com/p/jnaerator.